# null pointer exception while using Uid in firebase realtime database android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

whenever I try to upload data using Uid after google login it gives null pointer exception

**How to Push data to firebase real-time database in accordance with Uid**

I am new to android please help

my code

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class Register extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button val_btn;
    private EditText customer_name, company_name, mobile_no;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
    private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        customer_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ip_customer_name);
        company_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ip_company_name);
        mobile_no = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ip_mobile_no);

        val_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_validate);

        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        val_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String cust_name = customer_name.getText().toString().trim();
                String comp_name = company_name.getText().toString().trim();
                String mob_no = mobile_no.getText().toString().trim();

                HashMap<String, String> datamap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                datamap.put("Customer Name", cust_name);
                datamap.put("Company Name", comp_name);
                datamap.put("Mobile No", mob_no);

                String currentuser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

                mDatabase.child("Users").child(currentuser).setValue(datamap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Toast.makeText(Register.this, "updated  :)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(Register.this, "error  :(", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and the error is

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getUid()' on a null object reference

Comment: are you in the state of login?

Comment: yes, this activity won't open unless a user is logged n with google.

Answer (score 0):

`FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()` is returning null, which means a user is not signed in at the moment you called it.  Your code should check for that case, or use a listener to find out when a user is definitely signed in.

Comment: but this activity opens only after sign in so probably the user is successfully signed in.

Comment: I can't explain the circumstances that lead to the behavior you're seeing, but I can tell you that `getCurrentUser()` is documented to return null if the user is not signed in.  You will have to investigate on your own.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth#getCurrentUser()

Comment: So I did some research on that and found that you can use POJO class but can't find the way to get data from POJO class can you help.   Link to question:      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60921478/how-to-get-value-from-pojo-and-set-value-to-textview