# How to get value from POJO and set value to TextView

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can I get value from POJO and set its value to `TextView` in android studio
**MainActivity.java** onCreate method:

```
 FirebaseUser user=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

 assert user != null;

 String UserID=user.getUid();
 UserInfoPOJO userinfopojo = new UserInfoPOJO(UserID);
```

**UserInfoPOJO.java**

```
public class UserInfoPOJO {

    private String UserID;

    public UserInfoPOJO(String userID) {
        UserID = userID;
    }

    public String getUserID() {
        return UserID;
    }

    public void setUserID(String userID) {
        UserID = userID;
    }
}
```

**onCreate** method of **Main2Activity.java** contains:

please teach me how to set value to textview here

```
        userid1 = findViewById(R.id.op_uid);
        userinfopojo = (UserID);
        userid1.setText();
```

[image: snapshot of what i was trying to make]

Snapshot of what I was trying to make

this is not included in the question above.

I want to store data according to Uid

Comment: Please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot.

Comment: You want to read the userID or its attributes?

Comment: I want to share user-id `Uid` from my sign-in activity and use it in multiple activities hence I came up with POJO.

Comment: you can share userID by using Intent or maybe sharedPreference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `bVVz ... i322` is the id of the logged-in user, to get the values of `email`, `mobile` and `name`, please change the `UserInfoPOJO` class to:

```
class UserInfoPOJO {
    public String email, mobile, name;

    public UserInfoPOJO() {}
}
```

And to map the object from the database to an object of type `UserInfoPOJO`, please use the following lines of code:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child(uid);
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        UserInfoPOJO userInfoPOJO = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserInfoPOJO.class);
        String email = userInfoPOJ.email;
        String mobile = userInfoPOJ.mobile;
        String name = userInfoPOJ.name;
        Log.d("TAG", email + "/" + mobile + "/" + name);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d("TAG", databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The output in your logcat will be:

```
something@example.com/888888888/person name
```